# Understanding theorem in Apostol that specifies implicit solution of differential equation $P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$ when the latter is exact.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

There is a specific theorem that I would like to make sure I understand correctly.

Here is the statement of the theorem as it appears in Apostol's *Calculus*, Volume II, section 10.19 (on application of line integrals to exact differential equations of first order):

> **Theorem 10.7.** Assume that the differential equation
>
> $$P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0\tag{10.14}$$
>
> is exact in an open connected set $S$, and let $\varphi$ be a scalar
> field satisfying
>
> $$\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}=P$$
>
> $$\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial y}=Q$$
>
> everywhere in $S$. Then every solution $y=Y(x)$ of (10.14) whose graph
> lies in $S$ satisfies the equation $\varphi[x,Y(x)]=C$ for some
> constant $C$. Conversely, if the equation
>
> $$\varphi(x,y)=C$$
>
> defines $y$ implicitly as a differentiable function of $x$, then this
> function is a solution of the differential equation (10.14).

Note that a differential equation like that in (10.14) is said to be exact in $S$ if when we associate a vector field $V(x,y)=P(x,y)\hat{i}+Q(x,y)\hat{j}$ with it, the vector field is the gradient of some scalar field $\varphi$.

**Here is my interpretation of what this theorem says.**

If we have a differential equation that

1. we can write in the form 10.14, ie $P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$ and
2. the vector $\langle P(x,y), Q(x,y)\rangle$ is the gradient of a scalar field $\varphi$

then any solution $y(x)$ of the differential equation must satisfy $\varphi(x, y(x))=0$.

**My question is if the following paragraph is correct**

In other words, if the righthand side of 10.14 is the derivative of a scalar field $\varphi$ along a path $(x,y(x))$ then the fact that we are equating this derivative to zero means that $\varphi$ is constant along this path, ie $\varphi(x,y(x))=C$ for some $C$.

Here is a generic picture I drew to depict this latter paragraph

[image]

In this picture, the derivative of $\varphi(x,y(x)$ relative to $x$ equals zero and is our original differential equation.